Is Neovim able to use Terminal profile colors?
My terminal profile is set by time and changes between dark and light. The color-scheme is fine-tuned to my personal needs, I would love to make Neovim use the terminal colors profile.
Is it possible to apply no theme at all, but still have coloring?

check out this question, and my answer there https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/45122/5078

If you have in init.vim:
set notermguicolor

Neovim will use the termbg and termfg parameter of the colorscheme that reuse as much as possible the 16 color defined in your terminal settings.
To achieve what you want I would:

set noterminalguicolor
use a 16 colorscheme like dim

You could be interested by the following document: Consistent terminal colors with 16-ANSI-color Vim themes
You can also force Neovim to only use the first 16 color by having in your init.vim
set t_Co=16


thank you, that does exactly what I want.

Thanks for the feedback! I'm glad we could help you :-) Welcome to Vim!


Is it possible to apply no theme at all, but still have coloring?

No, because the syntax highlighting is provide by the theme. So the question doesn't make sense, but you probably want to disable the background colors.
See my answer on this question https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/45123/5078

I was wondering what it does to the syntax highlighting. You are right - mostly I want to get rid of the background coloring. My concern about only changing the background is, that if a dark theme is enabled in neovim, the text will usually be light. If then a light profile is enabled in the Terminal this could cause visibility problems.

There is no way around that. Themes have to contrast with the background. You need to set background=light or background=dark to inform syntax which one you want. Or pick a theme manually that has the syntax highlighting you want. Either way, if you're relying on the terminals background and telling the theme to ignore the background, you're going to have this liability.
